# Syncing CIVI CRM and Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, newsletter, sync

Has anyone synced CIVI CRM with a mailchimp account?

I work for a membership organisation and we need CIVI to track the data of our members and stay in control of our subscribe and unsubscribe lists. We are wondering whether anyone has used Mailchimp (or something similar) as it seems you can have more freedom with designing, but used it with CIVI so that you still have access to your mailing lists and data?

Any comments or suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are several CiviCRM-MailChimp integrations. The two still in common use are
[Mailchimpsync](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimpsync) and [Mailchimp CiviCRM integration](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration).

That said, it's been a long time since I've had a client use these for anything more than a transition period, since most are using [Mosaico](https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder) to get a better email template builder within CiviCRM.

The advantages are many, but primarily - Mailchimp can't send an email to everyone who attended an event in the last 90 days, or who lives within 30 miles of Peoria, or say, "Hey, your last donation was $25, could you increase that?" because it doesn't have that info available to it.